# Modify sub key in *plist files

Tags: shell, scripting, macos, plist

I'm would like to modify a subkey in a plist file (i.e. "TB Item Identifiers"):

```
NSNavPanelExpandedStateForSaveMode = 1;
NSPreferencesContentSize = "{508, 413}";
NSPreferencesSelectedIndex = 6;
"NSToolbar Configuration BrowserWindowToolbarIdentifier" =     {
    "TB Display Mode" = 2;
    "TB Icon Size Mode" = 1;
    "TB Is Shown" = 1;
    "TB Item Identifiers" =         (
        BackForwardToolbarIdentifier,
        HomeToolbarIdentifier,
        InputFieldsToolbarIdentifier
    );
    "TB Size Mode" = 1;
    "TB Visibility Priority Values" =         {
        BackForwardToolbarIdentifier =             (
            999
        );
        InputFieldsToolbarIdentifier =             (
            1000
        );
    };
};
```

I'm using the following command in a shell script :

```
defaults write com.apple.file key keyvalue
```

So each time I want to change "TB Item Identifiers", I'm modifying the entire "NSToolbar Configuration BrowserWindowToolbarIdentifier". How to directly modify a plist sub key or a sub sub key ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
defaults write com.yourcompany.app key -dict-add subkey plistValue
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the PlistBuddy

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "set Key:SubKey1:SubKey2:Subkey3 value" ./Path/To/Your.plist

Comment: This looks like a good sysadmin tool, too.  I was looking for a way to script turning off appstoreupdateagent in MacOS X 10.7, a.k.a. Lion.

Comment: However, PlistBuddy is for plists, and the defaults command is for the defaults database. It is an implementation detail that the defaults are cached on disk as plists. Not guaranteed (and not the same as what's in memory)